# Did I give a virus to my Django? manage.py disappearing

Tags: python, django, virus

My Django installation is falling a part - could I have a virus?

I recently installed : https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/

using pip and now very scary things are happening:

- **my manage.py in the root directory clears after every execution**
- even when I rename it something else, the starting script becomes a blank file
- The admin section of the app wont run at all.  I get errors
  like:

  [06/Feb/2015 06:27:48] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4308

  Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51159)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
      self.process_request(request, client_address)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 601, in process_request
      t = threading.Thread(target = self.process_request_thread,
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Thread'

What is really confusing is I had to comment out a settings line pertaining to “SessionAuthenticationMiddleware” or I get this

```
    File "/Users/rpanos/.virtualenvs/JiraStat_Local_JB/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 31, in import_by_path
        error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
    ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
```

Why would that suddenly be necessary?

### **If any one has any idea how these things are happening, please let me know.**

I already did a pip uninstall on django-pandas but I imagine there could be some nefarious remnant doing this?

My sincere apologies if django-pandas has nothing to do with this but my django install has been working great for a year and now all is going to crap!

Just in case another package might be the issue, please see my virtual environement here:

```
(JiraStat_Local_JB)Rs-Mac-mini:JiraStats rXXXXs$ lssitepackages
Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg-info        lxml-3.4.0-py2.7.egg-info       queuelib
OpenSSL                 model_utils             queuelib-1.2.2-py2.7.egg-info
Scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg-info        numpy                   requests
Twisted-14.0.2-py2.7.egg-info       numpy-1.9.0-py2.7.egg-info      requests-2.4.3-py2.7.egg-info
_cffi_backend.so            oauthlib                requests_oauthlib
_markerlib              oauthlib-0.6.3-py2.7.egg-info       requests_oauthlib-0.4.1-py2.7.egg-info
cffi                    pandas                  scrapy
cffi-0.8.6-py2.7.egg-info       pandas-0.14.1-py2.7.egg-info        setuptools
cryptography                pip                 setuptools-1.1.5-py2.7.egg-info
cryptography-0.6-py2.7.egg-info     pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info        six-1.8.0-py2.7.egg-info
cssselect               pkg_resources.py            six.py
cssselect-0.9.1-py2.7.egg-info      pkg_resources.pyc           six.pyc
dateutil                psycopg2                tlslite
django                  psycopg2-2.5.4-py2.7.egg-info       tlslite-0.4.6-py2.7.egg-info
django_model_utils-2.2-py2.7.egg-info   pyOpenSSL-0.14-py2.7.egg-info       twisted
easy_install.py             pycparser               w3lib
easy_install.pyc            pycparser-2.10-py2.7.egg-info       w3lib-1.10.0-py2.7.egg-info
jira                    python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg-info  zope
jira-0.32-py2.7.egg-info        pytz                    zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-nspkg.pth
lxml                    pytz-2014.7-py2.7.egg-info      zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7.egg-info
```

### UPDATE

django-pandas did downgrade my Django and that solved a couple problems.  Thank you Alasdair and Bernhard!  However, there seems to be another issue.

I had two poorly formed packages - ones that I made by hand because I thought I knew what I was doing - when I remove them, all of the issues with the manage.py script go away.  I usually trust PyCharm to do it, but these two I just copied the **init** files from another directory an started coding.

I have replaced and removed both of them to test this theory and its pretty solid.

### Could any of you Django experts guess why a bad package would cause Django to crash AND delete its own manage.py?

It was still deleting "itself" after I re-upgraded Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing `django-pandas` most likely downgraded your Django installation as it [explicitly requires Django < 1.7](https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/blob/master/setup.py#L24).

Answer (score 2):

`SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` was added in Django 1.7. The traceback suggests that you may have Django 1.6 or earlier installed.